# How can I quickly convert a BufferedImage to a byte[]?

Tags: java, optimization, bufferedimage

I need to convert a `BufferedImage` to a `byte[]`, but It is too slow. The byte is eventually base64 encoded and sent to an android client. The Method I have been using is like this:

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(BufferedImage im) throws IOException
{

//make sure its NN
if(im!=null)
{

//create a ByteArrayOutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//write our image to it
ImageIO.write( im, "png", baos );

//flush the stream
baos.flush();

//get the image in byte form
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

//close the stream
baos.close();

//return our value encoded in base64
return imageInByte;

}

return null;
}
```

This is far too slow for my program. Changing the `png` to `jpeg` makes it fail on the mobile side. The `JpegCodec` version also fails on the mobile side. By fail I mean the Android method `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` returns `null`.

Comment: It would be nice to know what `decodeByteArray()` accepts as arguments. The documentation "Decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array." isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: public static Bitmap decodeByteArray (byte[] data, int offset, int length) from the API

Comment: Yes but what's the format of the byte array? RGBA? ARGB? RGB? GBR? PNG? RAW?

Comment: PNG, I believe although I am not positive.

Comment: Some comments: 1. `flush()` isn't necessary. 2. You should `close()` the stream before calling `toByteArray()`. Yes, that will work :-)

Comment: I have done that, was that just a formatting based suggestion? I have no noticeable difference in speed(yes I am logging, I am not just going by sight).

Comment: Where is it spending most of the time?

Comment: ImageIO.write( im, "png", baos );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say why it's too slow and there isn't much that can be done to make this code faster because it's the only way to convert a `BufferedImage` to a PNG byte stream. But here are some pointers:

1. The class `ByteArrayOutputStream` is synchronized which costs a lot of performance. You can find a faster implementation in [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/io/) (`org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream`)
2. Depending on the size of your image, the allocation algorithm of `ByteArrayOutputStream` might be a problem. Start with an initial size of 1 or 10 KiB.
3. `toByteArray()` gives you a copy of the existing buffer. If you don't need that (and usually, you don't), writing your own `OutputStream` might give you an additional speed boost (not to mention avoiding GC runs)

Answer (score 1):

Would **not** converting to a byte[] be an option? You say "[it] is eventually base64 encoded and sent to an android client". What about wrapping the OutputStream to write to the Android client in something like [Base64OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) and avoiding the issue entirely?